# Other types of scripting languages for the web?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have never seen any other scripting language used on the web. Now this is out of curiosity, but are there any other languages besides JavaScript that are used on the web and are scripting languages? This might be a stupid question, but I have never seen any other languages used in the script tag.

Comment: VBscript is/was an option, though only IE supported it.

Comment: Why vote down that question ? Isn't it a good one ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer? No. JavaScript or as it is properly known [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) is the only client side scripting language available.

Long answer: Yes.

With plugins, people use [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript), [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight), and [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) to create dynamic content.

Chromium also supports [Dart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29), however Dart can be compiled into JavaScript and ran on any browser. [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript), like Dart, can also be compiled into JavaScript and ran in the browser.

The main reason that ECMAScript is the "only" client side language is that each and every browser has to implement their own version of the specification. This is why most vendors favour the use of plugins which enable their scripting language to run, rather than attempting to persuade browser vendors to implement a virtual machine for their language.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the real script behind everything is ECMAScript, and that everything else simply inherits?

Comment: But, I really liked the answer, it makes a lot of sense too.

Comment: Pretty much. As other answers have mentioned, there are a few specific implementations of scripting languages on specific browsers, but the only thing a developer can count on working on the majority of browsers is some (super/sub)set of ECMAScript, and so that's why many of the 'new' languages you see compile into ECMAScript.

Comment: @djlumley: You've got my attention: Do you have some more information about how to write such a plugin for a browser to implement a new scripting language?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft once added a [**VBScript**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) interpreter to Internet Explorer as an alternative to JavaScript. They also used the term [**JScript**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) instead of JavaScript for their own implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple type see this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp

Example of types:

> text/javascript (this is default)
>  text/ecmascript
>   application/ecmascript
>  application/javascript
>  text/vbscript
> text/jscript

Comment: w3fools again :) also `text/jscript`

Comment: text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/ecmascript,
application/javascript : all refer to the same Javascript AFAIK.

Comment: Don't know because in the link there is the full explanation and I have writeen some of example... uhm don't know why

Comment: @theredled: how very wrong. javascript is a dialect of ecmascript. they are not essentially the same

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: please add `text/jscript` too...

Comment: @naveen: in the current context "<script>", aren't all those type synonyms ? Otherwise there'd be specific text/actionscript available and so on.

Comment: @theredled Yeah I think "how very wrong" is stretching it a bit. It's analogous to the difference between "C" and "C99". It's fair to call ECMAScript and Javascript the "same language" for this purposes of this question...

Comment: @theredled: try running that on LTE IE8 :)

Answer (score 0):

VBScript, you can have java applets (they are old and gross I wouldn't) which pretty much sums up client side coding, then server side (CGI) you have things like PHP, ASP.NET, Python, C

Comment: Yea, I've seen Java Applets, but they are not exactly scripts are they? And yes, I hate them too, they are VERY slow.

Answer (score 0):

There are some languages that you can use if you load the correct parser:

- [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)
- [Processing](http://processing.org/)
- [Lively Kernel](http://www.lively-kernel.org/)
- and some more

See the [List of languages that compile to JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you check w3c you can find references for supported scripts.

Three main scripts specified over there are

1. JavaScript
2. VBScript
3. tcl

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

For more information on the types of scripts supported. Please go through this SO post

[What language types are allowed in the HTML script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872037/what-language-types-are-allowed-in-the-html-script-tag)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript would be the only one that's widely (if not universally) supported.

VBScript was available in IE as an alternative to JavaScript, but never took off.

Now there are plenty of languages that **compile into JavaScript** and can be used for front-end web development e.g.:

- [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)
- [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/)
- [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)
- [Script#](http://scriptsharp.com/)

Those won't be interpreted natively by the browser (except for Dart, which is supported in Chrome).

Comment: So that means that, <script language = "CoffeeScript"> is a valid argument in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to use a client side module loaders like requirejs that can for example load native Coffeescript files and compile them on the client.

However I would not do that as it increases loading and execution time.