# passing value to html input tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, vbscript

Hey guys I've got a bit of an issue passing values to a form input box.

It works fine with VBScript on IE, but not on Mozilla or Chrome, which means it won't work on any android devices.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="vbscript"> 
    dim TheForm
    set TheForm = document.forms("form1")
    TheForm.Text2.value="hai"
</script>
```

As far as I know Chrome and Firefox only accept `JavaScript` for this sorta thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myField').value = "hai";
</script>
```

Where:

```
<input type="text" id="myField" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, unfortunately the only standard (cross browser) scripting language in HTML pages is **JavaScript**.

See also [What language types are allowed in the HTML script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872037/what-language-types-are-allowed-in-the-html-script-tag)

That is why you can even use just `<script>` tag, without specifying the `language` (should have been `type` BTW) attribute, and every browser will default to JavaScript ([as recommended by HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)).

Now IE may accept other language(s), this is vendor-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same thing in javascript then you can do like following :

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    var TheForm;
    var TheForm = document.form1;
    TheForm.Text2.value="hai";
</script>
```